# Uri permission granted automatically

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a simple content provider that provides files to other apps. It extends `ContentProvider` (not `FileProvider`) and it's declared in the manifest like this:

```xml
<provider
    android:name="com.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true" />
```

The `query` method returns a simple cursor containing the following columns (`_display_name`, `_data` and `size`).

I also implemented `openAssetFile` which returns the same file.

I'm using the following code to share my URI with other apps:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("content://com.FileProvider/teste"))
intent.type = "image/*"

startActivity(intent)
```

The final path segment in the URI doesn't matter because the `query` method returns always the same cursor.

I'm successfully able to share the file with other apps, however, in no place am I giving read nor write permissions to this URI by calling `Context.grantUriPermission` nor through intent flags. The provider is not exported.

I've checked this behaviour in other app with a `FileProvider` implementation. The URIs were able to be shared even if they pointed to internal files.

Removing `android:grantUriPermissions="true"` results in the expected behaviour, so it seems that this line is automatically giving permissions. But that's not what the documentation says.

My question is, why am I able to share this URI if I gave no permissions for other apps to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm successfully able to share the file with other apps, however, in no place am I giving read nor write permissions to this URI by calling Context.grantUriPermission nor through intent flags.

Google added logic that automatically grants `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` in some scenarios, in what I think was a backwards-compatibility move. [`ACTION_SEND` was one of them](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html). I still steer developers towards adding the flags manually, in case some future Android version reverts this change (or a device manufacturer does), but technically it is not required.